# Как обратиться к определенному View в SwiftUI из другого класса

Tags: view, swiftui

В android можно сделать то, что мне нужно, с помощью findViewById(R.id.viewid) .

```
struct Test: View {
var body: some View {
    VStack
    {
        Text("OldText")
        Button(action: {
            //как поставить в текстовом поле выше "NewText"???
        }) {
            Text("MyButton")
        }
    }
}
```

}

Как обратиться из кода нажатия кнопки к текстовому полю выше?

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать обертку свойств `@State`. [Вот](https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/475078/) неплохая статья на эту тему

```
struct Test: View {

    @State private var text = "OldText"

    var body: some View {
        VStack
            {
                Text(text)
                Button(action: {
                    self.text = "NewText"
                }) {
                    Text("MyButton")
                }
        }
    }
}
```